# get the argument of directive function attribute and change it in another contoller angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a tree `directive` and I want when user clicked on some thing happens..it should be implement with who wants to use this tree. for example node's text changes.

**index.html**

```
<div ng-controller='TestController'>
        <tree model="treedata" on-node-clicked="changeNodeText($node)"></tree>
</div>
```

**Directive**

```
function treeDirectiveFactory() {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                scope: {
                    model: '=model',
                    collapseIcon: '=',//IIconProvider//TODO:
                    expandIcon: '=',//IIconProvider//TODO:
                    onNodeClicked:'&',//param:$node//TODO:
                    isExpanded:'@'
                },        
                templateUrl: '/_Core/DirectiveCore/Tree/TreeTemplate.html',
                controller: 'TreeController',
                controllerAs: 'c'

            }
};
```

**part of template**

```
<a href={{node.link()}} class="node-link" ng-click="c.onNodeClicked(node)"
   ng-class="{'margin-no-child':node['__$extension'].isLeaf(node)}">
    <span ng-bind-html="node.iconProvider().htmlPath()"></span>
    {{node.text()}}
</a>
```

when user click on node, **ng-click="c.onNodeClicked(node)"** will call and the node which is clicked is passed to **onNodeClicked** function. below is the implementation of this function in `controller as c` of tree `directive`

```
onNodeClicked(node: Core.INode) {//TODO:

        if (this.scope["onNodeClicked"]) {
            this.scope["onNodeClicked"] = ({$node:node});
        }
    }
```

I want to tell the function that you have an argument named **$node** and set the value of **$node**. then I want to change the **$node**  text in outer controller **TestController** in **index.html**...this is the **changeNodeText** function in **TestContoller**

```
f($node: Core.TestNode) {
        if($node !== undefined)
            $node.t = "Clicked!";
    }
```

but nothing changes, actually **changeNodeText** function never called. I know there is something wrong but unfortunately I can not figure it out. any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer for [@Parud0kht](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2126625/parid0kht)

Instead of setting the function, invoke it.

```
onNodeClicked(node: Core.INode) {//TODO:

        if (this.scope["onNodeClicked"]) {
            //Do THIS
            this.scope["onNodeClicked"]({$node:node});
            //Not THIS
            //this.scope["onNodeClicked"] = ({$node:node});
        }
    }
```

---

### Answer for Other Readers

This example does it with components, but the same principle applies to directives.

```
angular.module('app.dashboard')
    .component('dashboardComponent', {
        templateUrl: 'app/dashboard/directives/dashboard-container.html',
        controller: DashboardComponent,
        controllerAs: 'DashboardCtrl',
        bindings: {
            onTileChange: "&"
        }
    })t
```

To communicate event data from a component to a parent controller:

Instantiate the `dashboard-component` with:

```
<dashboard-component on-tile-change="HomeCtrl.onTileChange($tile)">
</dashboard-component>
```

In the component controller invoke the function with locals:

```
this.onTileChange({$tile: tile});
```

The convention for injected locals is to name them with a `$` prefix to differentiate them from variables on parent scope.

From the Docs:

> - `&` or `&attr` - provides a way to execute an expression in the context of the parent scope. If no attr name is specified then the attribute name is assumed to be the same as the local name. Given `<my-component my-attr="count = count + value">` and the isolate scope definition `scope: { localFn:'&myAttr' }`, the isolate scope property `localFn` will point to a function wrapper for the `count = count + value` expression. Often it's desirable to pass data from the isolated scope via an expression to the parent scope. This can be done by passing a map of local variable names and values into the expression wrapper fn. For example, if the expression is `increment($amount)` then we can specify the amount value by calling the `localFn` as `localFn({$amount: 22})`.

-- [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-)

Comment: you were the person who answered the question and then removed it ?? :)

Comment: Yes, you can look at the edit to see my previous answer. I was concerned that there was a name conflict between `this.scope.onNodeClicked` and `c.onNodeClicked`.

Comment: but your previous answer was fine at least for me. thanks for your new answer in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

someone answered my question completely right, but unfortunately the answer was removed so quickly, I was so lucky to saw it but I could not accept it as an answer..thanks to anonymous user for his or her great answer. hope he\she will see this answer and contact me.

I should `invoke` the function in **onNodeClicked** not set it..how crazy I am !! :))) here is the answer which is working well.

```
onNodeClicked(node: Core.INode) {

            if (this.scope["onNodeClicked"]) {
                //invoking, function should be called.
                this.scope["onNodeClicked"]({ $node: node });
                //this is wrong and it will set an object 
                //this.scope["onNodeClicked"] = ({ $node: node });

            }
}
```